# How to read MongoDB array in java

Tags: java, mongodb-query

I wrote query in MongoDB which retrieved two columns, one for id and the other is array. I have tried to read the array using Java but I cannot.

```
try {     
    Bson filter = eq("_id", "1260718680159199238");
    Bson project = eq("Tweets.Text", 1L);

    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(
        new MongoClientURI(
            "mongodb://localhost:27017/?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass%20Isolated%20Edition&ssl=false"
        )
    );
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("Amazon-tweets");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("tweets");
    FindIterable<Document> result = collection.find(filter).projection(project);

    for (Document doc : result) {
        String s = doc.getString("Tweets.1");
        System.out.println("orig   " + s);
    }
}//END try
catch (Exception e) {

}//
```

Comment: I recommend you to debug and check the value for the 'collection' variable - check if its null or empty first? and update the question - this will help others to answer the question

Comment: Can you post a sample JSON. We can help you out after seeing the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the dot notation to retrieve values like that post query.
Depending on the driver version you're using you can use either of these solutions:

(I'm assuming each tweet is a separate document here, but same should apply if it's something different)

```java
List<Document> tweets = (List<Document>) doc.get("Tweets");
List<Document> tweets = doc.getList("Tweets", Document.class); // since 3.10

tweets.forEach(...
```

You can find the documentation here: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/